# else if statement efficiency in variable allocation

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms, if-statement

I have JavaScript that takes the entry from a form and then searches the location after using "GET" to apply these form inputs to values, as you can see it ends up with me using a for statement couple by a very long if/else if statement. What is the best way to make this more efficient?

Thank you!

```
var search = location.search;
var parts = search.slice(1).split('&');    // Need to slice to remove initial '?'
for (var i=0; i < parts.length; ++i)
{
  var info = parts[i].split('=');
  var variable = info[0];
  var value = info[1];
  if(variable === "pNAME") {
            var pNAME = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "mAB") {
            var mAB = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "mPB") {
            var mPB = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "mNA") {
            var mNA = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lPED") {
            var lPED = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lSS") {
            var lSS = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lSC") {
            var lSC = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lVIS") {
            var lVIS = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lPAR") {
            var lPAR = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lBUS") {
            var lBUS = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "lTRAIN") {
            var lTRAIN = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cHT") {
            var cHT = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cRAM") {
            var cRAM = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cTMS") {
            var cTMS = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cCC") {
            var cCC = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cCG") {
            var cCG = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cSTRL") {
            var cSTRL = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "cWEAL") {
            var cWEAL = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "deWHI") {
            var deWHI = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "deASI") {
            var deASI = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "deBLA") {
            var deBLA = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "deOTH") {
            var deOTH = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "daYOU") {
            var daYOU = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "daYM") {
            var daYM = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "daM") {
            var daM = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "daOL") {
            var daOL = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "doPOP") {
            var doPOP = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "doDENS") {
            var doDENS = value;      
  }
  else if(variable === "doSTU") {
            var doSTU = value;      
  }
};
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: How do you use these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an object out of it and assign the variable as property, using the variable 
name as property name. Something like:

```
  var myVar = {};
  for (var i=0; i < parts.length; ++i){
    var info = parts[i].split('=');
    myVar[info[0]] = info[1];
  }
```

Now you have all your variables and values in one Object, addressable for example as `myVar.lSS` or `myVar.pNAME`.

Comment: Works perfectly, much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

put your pNAME,mAB... also in array and than do so

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
var length = haystack.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
}
return false;
```

}